# problem changing input type in pytorch reinforcement learning

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to tun a code I found on github, but keep crashing in one part and getting `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars` error. I've been trying to solve it for two days now. If I understand the problem correctly I have incompatible dtypes of tensors yet I've no idea how to fix this. Everytime I try to change my tensor type to say DoubleTensor, or float64 I get other errors. I simply haven't got a clue now which part needs to be changed and how.

This is my model defined:

```
class Policy(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):      
        super(Policy, self).__init__()
        self.input_layer = nn.Linear(11, 128)
        self.hidden_1 = nn.Linear(128, 128)
        self.hidden_2 = nn.Linear(32,31)
        self.hidden_state = torch.tensor(torch.zeros(2,1,32)).cuda()
        self.rnn = nn.GRU(128, 32, 2)
        self.action_head = nn.Linear(31, 5)
        self.value_head = nn.Linear(31, 1)
        self.saved_actions = []
        self.rewards = []

    def reset_hidden(self):
        self.hidden_state = torch.tensor(torch.zeros(2,1,32)).cuda()
        
    def forward(self, x): 
        x = torch.tensor(x).cuda()
        x = torch.sigmoid(self.input_layer(x))
        x = torch.tanh(self.hidden_1(x))
        x, self.hidden_state = self.rnn(x.view(1,-1,128), self.hidden_state.data)
        x = F.relu(self.hidden_2(x.squeeze()))
        action_scores = self.action_head(x)
        state_values = self.value_head(x)
        return F.softmax(action_scores, dim=-1), state_values

        def forward(self, x):
          conv_out = self.conv(x).view(x.size()[0], -1)
          val = self.fc_val(conv_out)
          adv = self.fc_adv(conv_out)
          return val + (adv - adv.mean(dim=1, keepdim=True))
    
    def act(self, state):
        probs, state_value = self.forward(state)
        m = Categorical(probs)
        action = m.sample()
        if action == 1 and env.state[0] < 1: action = torch.LongTensor([2]).squeeze().cuda.DoubleTensor()
        if action == 4 and env.state[1] < 1: action = torch.LongTensor([2]).squeeze().cuda.DoubleTensor()
        if action == 6 and env.state[2] < 1: action = torch.LongTensor([2]).squeeze().cuda.DoubleTensor()
        self.saved_actions.append((m.log_prob(action), state_value))
        return action.item()
```

This is where it crashes

```
env.reset()
# In case you're running this a second time with the same model, delete the gradients
del model.rewards[:]
del model.saved_actions[:]

gamma = 0.9
log_interval = 60

def finish_episode():
    R = 0
    saved_actions = model.saved_actions
    policy_losses = []
    value_losses = []
    rewards = []
    for r in model.rewards[::-1]:
        R = r + (gamma * R)
        rewards.insert(0, R)
    rewards = torch.tensor(rewards)
    
    epsilon = (torch.rand(1) / 1e4) - 5e-5
    # With different architectures, I found the following standardization step sometimes
    # helpful, sometimes unhelpful.
    #
    rewards = (rewards - rewards.mean()) / (rewards.std(unbiased=False) + epsilon)
    # Alternatively, comment it out and use the following line instead:
    rewards += epsilon
    
    for (log_prob, value), r in zip(saved_actions, rewards):
        reward = torch.tensor(r - value.item()).cuda()
        policy_losses.append(-log_prob * reward)
        value_losses.append(F.smooth_l1_loss(value, torch.tensor([r]).cuda()))
        
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss = torch.stack(policy_losses).sum() + torch.stack(value_losses).sum()
    loss = torch.clamp(loss, -1e-5, 1e5)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    del model.rewards[:]
    del model.saved_actions[:]

running_reward = 0
for episode in range(0, 4000):
    state = env.reset()
    state = state.type(torch.float32)
    reward = 0
    done = False
    msg = None 
    while not done:
        action = model.act(state)
        state, reward, done, msg = env.step(action)
        model.rewards.append(reward)
        if done:
            break
    running_reward = running_reward * (1 - 1/log_interval) + reward * (1/log_interval)
    finish_episode()
    # Resetting the hidden state seems unnecessary - it's effectively random from the previous
    # episode anyway, more random than a bunch of zeros.
    # model.reset_hidden()
    if msg["msg"] == "done" and env.portfolio_value() > env.starting_portfolio_value * 1.1 and running_reward > 500:
        print("Early Stopping: " + str(int(reward)))
        break
    if episode % log_interval == 0:
        print("""Episode {}: started at {:.1f}, finished at {:.1f} because {} @ t={}, \
last reward {:.1f}, running reward {:.1f}""".format(episode, env.starting_portfolio_value, \
              env.portfolio_value(), msg["msg"], env.cur_timestep, reward, running_reward))
```

This is the error I get

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:18: UserWarning: To copy construct from a tensor, it is recommended to use sourceTensor.clone().detach() or sourceTensor.clone().detach().requires_grad_(True), rather than torch.tensor(sourceTensor).
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-21b617d2e36f> in <module>()
     46     msg = None
     47     while not done:
---> 48         action = model.act(state)
     49         state, reward, done, msg = env.step(action)
     50         model.rewards.append(reward)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in linear(input, weight, bias)
   1751     if has_torch_function_variadic(input, weight):
   1752         return handle_torch_function(linear, (input, weight), input, weight, bias=bias)
-> 1753     return torch._C._nn.linear(input, weight, bias)
   1754 
   1755 

RuntimeError: expected scalar type Double but found Float
```

This is the github I'm using:
https://github.com/tomgrek/RL-stocktrading/blob/master/Finance%20final.ipynb

I was suggested that teh problem is because when I use "state" as a parameter torch throws an error cause it expects a numeric type, but I cannot change state to any float, because I get another error that list can't be changed to float32.

I'll be super grateful if you could show me idiot-proof what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You have to transform the output of the `env.step(action)` to a tensor, simply `torch.Tensor(state)`

Comment: I'm sorry for a stupid question, but do you mean `torch.Tensor(state), reward, done, msg = env.step(action)`? It throws me this error `can't assign to function call` so I guess, I'm mistaken..

Comment: In your code, `state` must be a Tensor since it passes through the network. Make sure it is always as such. Moreover, bear in mind that you are resetting the environment at every iteration, perhaps it is not what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

First are you using the same environment "env" and/or dataset ?

Second, you added this line state = state.type(torch.float32) and it didn't throw an error so I suppose state was already a tensor (which is a bit weird). If you had to change the type to float32 then in the next while loop you may have forgotten to change the type.

```
while not done:
    action = model.act(state)  
    state, reward, done, msg = env.step(action)  
    state = state.float()  # To add as I think env.step(action) returns a long tensor for some reason
    model.rewards.append(reward)  
    if done:  
        break
```

Good luck.